# How to display a small icon into the right side of a QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I have a QTreeView which display data from a SQLite database via peewee ORM.
The QTreeView has filters and sorting enabled.
For filtering I display a QLineEdit into the column header.

Question: how could I display a small clear-icon into the right-hand side of the QLineEdit which is filled (=has some text). When clicking the delete-icon the related QLineEdit should be cleared.

Expected result:

[image]

Current result:
[image]

Full working code example (peewee necessary):

```
import sys
import re
from peewee import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore 

COUNT_PERS_COLS = 3
col_persID, col_persLAST_NAME, col_persFIRST_NAME = range(COUNT_PERS_COLS)

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

def _human_key(key):
    parts = re.split(r'(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key)
    return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e))
            for i, e in enumerate(parts))

class FilterHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    filterActivated = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self._editors = []
        self._padding = 4
        self.setStretchLastSection(True)        
        self.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.sectionResized.connect(self.adjustPositions)
        parent.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.adjustPositions)

    def setFilterBoxes(self, count):
        while self._editors:
            editor = self._editors.pop()
            editor.deleteLater()
        for index in range(count):
            editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.parent())
            editor.setPlaceholderText('Filter')
            editor.returnPressed.connect(self.filterActivated.emit)
            self._editors.append(editor)
        self.adjustPositions()

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super().sizeHint()
        if self._editors:
            height = self._editors[0].sizeHint().height()
            size.setHeight(size.height() + height + self._padding)
        return size

    def updateGeometries(self):
        if self._editors:
            height = self._editors[0].sizeHint().height()
            self.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, height + self._padding)
        else:
            self.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        super().updateGeometries()
        self.adjustPositions()

    def adjustPositions(self):
        for index, editor in enumerate(self._editors):
            height = editor.sizeHint().height()
            editor.move(
                self.sectionPosition(index) - self.offset() + 2,
                height + (self._padding // 2))
            editor.resize(self.sectionSize(index), height)

    def filterText(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._editors):
            return self._editors[index].text()
        return ''

    def setFilterText(self, index, text):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._editors):
            self._editors[index].setText(text)

    def clearFilters(self):
        for editor in self._editors:
            editor.clear()        


class HumanProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self, source_left, source_right):
        data_left = source_left.data()
        data_right = source_right.data()
        if type(data_left) == type(data_right) == str:
            return _human_key(data_left) < _human_key(data_right)
        return super(HumanProxyModel, self).lessThan(source_left, source_right)

    @property
    def filters(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_filters"):
            self._filters = []
        return self._filters

    @filters.setter
    def filters(self, filters):
        print(f"filters() called.")        

        self._filters = filters
        self.invalidateFilter()                

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):        
        for i, text in self.filters:
            if 0 <= i < self.columnCount():
                ix = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, i, sourceParent)                
                data = ix.data()
                if text not in data:
                    return False            
        return True        


class Person(Model):
    persId = CharField()
    lastName = CharField()
    firstName = CharField() 

    class Meta:
        database = db


class winMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        
        super().__init__(parent)                
        self.setupUi()
        self.setGeometry(300,200,700,500)        

        self.show()        

    def createPersonModel(self,parent):        
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, COUNT_PERS_COLS, parent)                
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Last Name', 'First Name'])

        return model

    def addPerson(self, model, id, last_name, first_name):        
        model.insertRow(0)        
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persID), id)
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persLAST_NAME), last_name)
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persFIRST_NAME), first_name)

    def handleFilterActivated(self):                
        header = self.treeView.header()
        filters = []

        for i in range(header.count()):
            text = header.filterText(i)
            if text:        
                filters.append((i, text))

        proxy = self.treeView.model()
        proxy.filters = filters        

    def setupUi(self):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)        
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)        

        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)        

        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)        
        self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.treeView.setAnimated(True)
        self.treeView.setItemsExpandable(True)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        header = FilterHeader(self.treeView)        
        self.treeView.setHeader(header)        

        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)        

        model = self.createPersonModel(self)
        self.treeView.setModel(model)

        proxy = HumanProxyModel(self)
        proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        self.treeView.setModel(proxy)        

        header.setFilterBoxes(model.columnCount())
        header.filterActivated.connect(self.handleFilterActivated)

        for rec_person in Person.select():            
            self.addPerson(model, rec_person.persId, rec_person.lastName, rec_person.firstName)        

if __name__ == '__main__':                         
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)         

    db.create_tables([Person])

    # create some sample data
    Person.create(persId='1001', lastName='Martin', firstName='Robert')
    Person.create(persId='1002', lastName='Smith', firstName='Brad')
    Person.create(persId='1003', lastName='Smith', firstName='Angelina')        

    window = winMain()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: add `editor.setClearButtonEnabled(True)`

Comment: Aaargh. Thanks! Didn't knew this property exists! :-( Thought I'd have to paint this all by mysyelf.

Comment: You have to read the documentation, SO it is not a shortcut.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Sorry! :'-(
I had no clue that I would be able to find such a thing, so I was not searching in the docu for it! My bad!

Comment: Also do not abuse the tags. Does your problem have to do with peewee or sqlite? Well, no. Your SW can have many dependencies but in SO we are not interested in your SW, we are interested in your problem.

Comment: Ok, got that! Agreed!